# SonarQube: Configure VSTS to analysis GitHub Pull Requests

Tags: github, sonarqube, azure-devops

I am using VSTS for CI and CD. We have a workflow which involves pull requests in Github. These are automatically built and tested by VSTS.

I am trying to add SonarQube analysis to this workflow.

I have tried adding the SonarQube VSTS plugin from the marketplace and then passing the github parameters to the SonarQube prepare analysis step.

[image: Step Settings]

However, this seems to have no effect.

I also tried running locally the sonar-scanner command line and I see the following comment on my PR but I know there are issues.

[image: Comment on pull request]

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't seem like it should be this hard to get it to work.

I guess my main questions are:

1. How do I set up SonarQube to correctly do a preview analysis of my github pull request?
2. How can I integrate this process with VSTS?

Update: I am using SonarQube 6.7.1 and v4.0 of the SonarQube MSBuild tool.

Comment: As you see the status of the PR being updated (like what I can see on your screenshot), this means that the analysis is working "correctly". Now, to get issues, you must be sure that this analysis is running on the code of the PR - not on the target branch (which would explain why you get 0 issues because you are basically analyzing the same code). Can you double check this point?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam but that comment only appears if I run sonar-scanner locally - not via VSTS. I'll have a look into your suggestion though. Any hints on getting this to work? Will the VSTS plugin actually work with the github plugin?

Comment: I don't see why it would not work on VSTS. You can compare the logs you have on VSTS with the ones you get locally to see if the GitHub plugin gets executed in both cases - that might help debug what's going on.

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett Can you show the detail build logs by setting the variable `system.debug` as `true`? And what's the build agent did you use, is it Hosted agent or private agent which SonarQube is installed?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will have another go tomorrow and update. I've added that I am using SonarQube 6.7.1 and I think it is version 4 of the MSbuild plugin.